# I always receive a score of 0

Tags: android

I have asked this question before but have received little to no help.
I seriously don't understand what's wrong.
The point of this code is, when a button is pressed, to check if the checklists are checked, add 1 to the score if it is checked, check the score value and assign an output to text

```
package xyz.ashraf.whoisdelasalle;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;

/**
 * Created by Ashraf on 3/2/2016.
 */
public class check_Button extends Pop_sallian{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.popwindow_sallian);
        // Connects The variable to an xml id


        TextView output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);

        int score = 0;
        //sets the variable to 0


         OnCheckedChangeListener checkedListener = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                switch(buttonView.getId()){
                    case R.id.concern:
                        score++;
                        break;
                    case R.id.faith:
                        score++;
                        break;
                    case R.id.respect:
                        score++;
                        break;
                    case R.id.education:
                        score++;
                        break;
                    case R.id.community:
                        score++;
                        break;
                }
            }
        };

        // adds the variables together to form a score

        if(score == 0){
            output.setText("score of 0");
        } else if(score == 1){
            output.setText("score of 1");
        } else if(score == 2){
            output.setText("score of 2");
        } else if(score == 3){
            output.setText("score of 3");
        } else if(score == 4){
            output.setText("score of 4");
        } else if(score == 5){
            output.setText("score of 5");
        } else{
            output.setText("Unknown");
        }
        // changes the output text based on score value
    }
}
```

^^checklist code^^

```
    package xyz.ashraf.whoisdelasalle;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;

    /**
     * Created by Ashraf on 1/27/2016.
     */
    public class Pop_sallian extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.popwindow_sallian);

            DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

            int width = dm.widthPixels;
            int height = dm.heightPixels;

            getWindow().setLayout((int)(width*.8),(int)(height*.6));

            Button checkButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.check);
            checkButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(Pop_sallian.this, check_Button.class));
// calls the checklist class
                }
            });
            Button okButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.okButton_sallian);
            okButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    finish();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

^^Code where the button is and, when pressed calls on the checklist code^^

Thanks, for your help

Answer (score -1):

seem that you haven't set event for button.

This variable : checkedListener not used yet.

So the score value alway equals 0.

Comment: Thanks for replying, so how would I set an event?

Comment: `you haven't set event for button.` Are you serious? So, what is this `okButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {`? The fact is that the OP calls `finish()`, instead of performing some actions.

Comment: Ok button closes the pop up when pressed